# Why is my CSS background repeating twice down the page?

Tags: css, background

The code below is creating the desired background but duplicating it twice down the page. Why is this and how can it be prevented? I am testing this in Google Chrome.

```css
body {
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
  border: 20px solid black;
  background: radial-gradient(at top left, lightgreen, blue);
}
```

Comment: Only twice? It is repeated indefinitely, due to `background-repeat: repeat`

Comment: add background-repeat: no-repeat to the body and it won't repeat

Comment: `background: radial-gradient(at top left, lightgreen, blue) no-repeat;` check if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oriol is right, you have to add the `background-repeat` property to your CSS.

So just add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and you should see that your background doesn't repeat. This also works for background images.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css

```
body {
   border-top-left-radius: 200px;
   border: 20px solid black;
   background: radial-gradient(at top left, lightgreen, blue);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to mention `background-repeat` and `background-size` property.

**Css**

```
body {
  border-top-left-radius: 200px;
  border: 20px solid black;
  background: radial-gradient(at top left, lightgreen, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```